# The CSS Grid System or Media Queries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure if I should use the grid system or the (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-html-responsive-by-adding-a-single-line-of-css-2a62de81e431)  or media queries.

I find that my side menu bar as well as my featured products at the bottom change do to the width of the computer.

I am not sure css grids will help as I am concerned more about how the menu bars play with each other, yet stay in their correct relation to each other.  Not sure how to fix this.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Healthy Hair Beauty Supply</title>
      <style>body {
      background: url('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/red-gold-background-frame-roses-vector-79285044.jpg') no-repeat;
      font-family: Apple Chancery, cursive;
      font-style: italic;
      color: gold;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: .81;
    }
    section {
      background-color: #1b0007;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 1px #FFEF99;
      opacity: .8;
      padding: 10px;
      float: right;
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      color: white;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    }
    ul  {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style: none;
    }
    ol {list-style:none;
    width:200px;            
    }
    ul li {
      box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 1px #FFEF99;
      border-radius: 5px;
      float: right;
      width: 240px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: .4;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 8px;
    }
    ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: gold;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
      background-color: red;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    ul li ul li {
      display: none;
    }
    ul li:hover ul li {
      display: block;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #34000d;
      font-size: 40px;
      padding: 60px;
      box-shadow: 12px 12px 2px 1px #34000d;
      text-align: center;
      Opacity: .7;
      background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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') no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
    span {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .engraved {
      font-size: 100px;
      font-family: Futura;
      background-color: #000000;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -moz-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5) 3px 5px 1px;
    }
    .embossed {
      color: #f0f0f0;
      font-size: 100px;
      font-family: Futura;
      background-color: #666666;
              text-shadow: 1px 4px 4px #555;
              text-align: center;
              -webkit-background-clip: text;
              -moz-background-clip: text;
              }
            </style>
            </head>
              <body>
                <ul>
                  <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Affliates</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>About Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Testimonial</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Contact Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <ul>
            <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Reviews</a>
              <ul>
                <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Youtube</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
             <ul>
          <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Hair Growth </a>
            <ul>
             <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>OIL</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <ul>
            <li style="width: 140px;font-size:small;"><a>Home</a>                  
            </li>               
              <br><br><br>
              <span class="engraved">
                <h1 style="font-size:85%;">
    Healthy Hair Beauty Supply
    </h1></span>
    <div class="banner"><a href="https://www.affilorama.com/5stepformula?aff=clarissagr"><img src="https://cdn.affilorama.com/files/image/affiliates/resources/affilojetpack/banner/72890-A.png" style="width:100%;display:grid;"></a></div>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    <section style="width:800px; height:275px;left:100px; display: grid;">What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</section>
    <ol>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care products</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care growth products</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care growth oil product</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care natural hair blog</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care blog</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care forum</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care product development</li>
    <li style="font-size:85%;background-color: #1b0007;
      opacity: .8;">black hair care reviews</li>
    </ol>                             
              </div>
    <div style="position: relative;
    top: 100px; right:850px;">
         <section>  
        <h2 style="font-size:70%;">
           Featured Healthy Hair Product
        </h2>
        <p>
          <div class="product">
            <a href="#" class="img"><img src="http://www.hydrathermanaturals.com/DSN/wwwhydrathermanaturalscom/Commerce/productimages/tmb1_000018.jpg"/style="width:80px; height:80px;" ></a>                
            </div>
            <div style="font-size:25%;"><a href="#" class="name">Hair Product</a>
            <div>
              $19.00
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="cart">Shopping Cart</a>
            <span>1</span>                
    </p>
    </div>
    </section>
          </div>
          </div>
    <div style="position: relative;right:350px;top:100px;">
    <section>
             <h2 style="font-size:70%">
           Featured Healthy Hair Product
        </h2>
        <p>
          <div class="product">
            <a href="#" class="img"><img src="http://www.hydrathermanaturals.com/DSN/wwwhydrathermanaturalscom/Commerce/productimages/tmb1_000018.jpg"/style="width:80px; height:80px;" ></a>                              
            </div>
            <div style="font-size:25%;"><a href="#" class="name">Hair Product</a>
            <div>
              $19.00
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="cart">Shopping Cart</a>
            <span>1</span>                
    </p>
    </section>
          </div>
    </div>         
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are not satisfied with how the 'menu bars' are arranged when changing the width of the screen? If so, specify how should they.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/532619b28c1ccc0cac002730

> ..."well, the simple solution would be this:
>   body {
>   padding: 0;
>   margin: 0;"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend css-grid, it's versatile, and saves you a lot of time when you first get a hang of it, i would recommend looking into the documentation and/or some tutorials.

Here's a tutorial, that shows you the main functions of GRID:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

And here's a game for motivated practice
http://cssgridgarden.com/

Comment: My concern is it' ability to change and yet stay aligned with the contents

Answer (score 0):

I think for responsive design you will still have to use media queries even if you  use CSS grid. I've used CSS grid and still had to use media queries to change how my grid looks at different viewport sizes.

Comment: what helped you to understand and implement css grids?